# Php lookahead assertion at the end of the regex

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write a regex with assertions to extract the number 55 from string `unknownstring/55.1`, here is my regex

```
    $str = 'unknownstring/55.1';
    preg_match('/(?<=\/)\d+(?=\.1)$/', $str, $match);
```

so, basically I am trying to say give me the number that comes after slash, and is followed by a dot and number 1, and after that there are no characters. But it does not match the regex. I just tried to remove the `$` sign from the end and it matched. But that condition is essential, as I need that to be the end of the string, because the `unknownstring` part can contain similar text, e.g. `unknow/545.1nstring/55.1`. Perhaps I can use preg_match_all, and take the last match, but I want understand why the first regex does not work, where is my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Without regex you can split on / and take everything before the dot

Comment: @MarcoMura yeah alternatives exist, as one was mentioned as well, just wanted to know my mistake. tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anchor `$` inside lookahead:

```
(?<=\/)\d+(?=\.1$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB0xQ8/1)

You cannot use `$` outside the positive lookahead because your number is NOT at the end of input and there is a `\.1` following it.